# Grid View Qml Item hide with cell

Tags: qml

I have a problem with GridView in QML, I created a calendar for the month, each cell of the GridView is for a day, and within put an item for each event having that day, I try to move this item within the cells but when I try to move it to the right, is hidden in the cell of GridView, this does not happen when I move the item to the cell to the left, attached the full code in case I have alguan idea to fix, greetings.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1D667C304F6D1F70!1638&authkey=!AP_pyb07rfu1Gg0&ithint=file%2c.zip

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window {
visible: true
width: 360
height: 360

GridView
{
     id: grid
     x:0
     y:0
     interactive: false//para que no se mueva la rejilla

     highlightFollowsCurrentItem: false
     highlightRangeMode:GridView.StrictlyEnforceRange
     anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
     width: parent.width
     cellWidth: parent.width / 7
     cellHeight: parent.height / 6
     anchors.top://parte para inculir la fila del nombre de las fechas
     {
         return parent.top
     }
     model: 42
     delegate: MonthCellBig{}

     flickableChildren: MouseArea
     {
         anchors.fill: parent
         onClicked:
         {
             mouseToPosition(mouse.x, mouse.y)
         }
     }
 }
    //necesario para crear un nuevo item
    function mouseToTimePosition(mouseX, mouseY)
    {
        //if(mouseY < 0 || mouseY > appwnd.height) return;

        var columnID = Math.floor(mouseX / grid.cellWidth);
        var rowID = Math.floor(mouseY / grid.cellHeight);
        var offset = Math.floor(((rowID * 7) + columnID) + 1);

        //var day = offset - m_monthStartAt + 1;

        return {dia: offset}
    }

    // para conseguir el dia donde ha echo click el usuario
    function mouseToPosition(mouseX, mouseY)
    {
        var cellData = mouseToTimePosition(mouseX, mouseY)
        //console.log(cellData.dia)
    }
```

}

MonthCellBig.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle
{
id: parentRectangle
width: grid.cellWidth - 1
height: grid.cellHeight - 1


Rectangle
{
    id: rectangleCell
    color: "transparent"
    anchors.fill: parent
    //para la separacion entre las lineas del rectangle
    anchors.leftMargin: -1
    anchors.rightMargin: -1
    anchors.topMargin: -1
    anchors.bottomMargin: -1

    Column
    {
        id:columnItem
        //y: txtNumberDay.height + 3
        spacing: 2

        Repeater
        {
            model: 2
            Rectangle
            {
                id: itemData

                width: rectangleCell.width; height: txtItem.height; radius: 10; color: "green"

                Text
                {
                    id: txtItem
                    text: qsTr("text")
                }

                MouseArea
                {
                    id: mouseArea
                    acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    width: grid.rectWidth - 5
                    height: grid.rectHeight - 5
                    drag.target: itemData
                    drag.axis: Drag.XAxis

                    //onClicked:{ grid.End; console.log("EEE");}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is because of the z property. Each item created would be placed "on top" of previous item so when you move to the left you see it but to the right it is hidden behind. Try adding z: 1000  to your Item

Comment: Hello, the property z:1000 in the item does not work

Comment: You should try reproducing the issue with a small GridView example and past the code here instead of linking your whole project